# Simple image slider not working (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I am creating a simple slider using jQuery.

**The problem:** The slider is disappearing and/or collapsing (you can see it when you refresh before it disappears).

What I'm trying to do: Make the positions of the images `absolute` and then using JavaScript show the `nth` index using the `display` property in the script.

Not sure if it is the css or the JavaScript that is making it hidden. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#sidebar-btn').click(function() {
    $('#sidebar-nav').toggleClass('visible');
  });
});

var index = 0;

function plusIndex(n) {
  index = index + 1;
  showImage(index);
}

/* SLIDER */
showImage(1);

/* Slider function */
function showImage(n) {

  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slider-img");

  // for next slide - forward.
  if(n > x.length) { index = 1 };
  // for prev slide - backwards
  if(n < 1 ) { index = x.length /* last one */ };
  for(i=0; i<x.length; i++) 
  {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[index-1].style.display = "block";  
}
```

```css
.updates-box {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2rem;
}
.updates-item-headline {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.updates-item {
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 1rem auto;
}

.slider {
  position: relative;

}
.slider-img {
  position: absolute;

}
.slider .slider-btn {
  position: absolute; 
  color: black;
  width: 50px;
  border:none;
  border-radius: 25px;
  top: 190px; 
  font-size: 35px;
  margin:  1rem;
}
.slider #slide-btn2 {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}
.slider #slide-btn1:hover {
  box-shadow: 10px 0px 20px  0px black;
}
.slider #slide-btn2:hover {
  box-shadow: 10px 0px 20px  0px black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hero-box">
  <div id="slide-wrapper">
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="slide">
        <picture>
           <source media="(max-width: 620px)" srcset="img/hero-slider-mobile.jpg">
            <source media="(min-width: 621)" srcset="img/hero-slider-tablet.jpg">
           <img class="slider-img" src="img/hero-slider-home.jpg" alt="Flowers">
        </picture>      
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <picture>
           <source media="(max-width: 620px)" srcset="img/slide-2-mobile.jpg">
            <source media="(min-width: 621)" srcset="img/slide-2-tablet.jpg">
           <img class="slider-img" src="img/slide-2-home.jpg" alt="Flowers">
        </picture>      
      </div>
      <button class="slider-btn" id="slide-btn1">&#10094;</button>
      <button class="slider-btn" id="slide-btn2">&#10095;</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="updates-box">
  <div class="updates-item-headline">
    <p> UPCOMING EVENT DATES</p>
  </div>
  <div class="updates-item">
    <img class="update-icon" src="img/dates-icon.png">
    <p><b>Thursday 3 August</b></p>
    <p> Open Seminar Enrollment</p>
  </div>
  <div class="updates-item">
    <img class="update-icon" src="img/dates-icon.png">
    <p><b>Thursday 3 August</b></p>
    <p> Open Seminar Enrollment</p>
  </div>
    <div class="updates-item-4">
    <img class="update-icon" src="img/dates-icon.png">
    <p><b>Thursday 3 August</b></p>
    <p> Open Seminar Enrollment</p>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code snippet... You have the error:

> Cannot read property 'style' of undefined"

That error says `x[index-1]` is undefined.
It **IS undefined** because `index` is defined in one of the two `if` conditions above... Which both evaluate to `false`.

1. In `if(n > x.length)`: n = 1 and x.length = 2
2. In `if(n < 1 )`: n = 1

So `index` is "undefined".

Then comes a `for` loop, setting all images to `display:none`.
*That is why you may see them a couple milliseconds on refresh.*

And finally, `x[index-1]` also is undefined.. So no image is setted back to `display:block`.

**I suggest** you to add a case where the condition could be evaluated to `true`:

```
if(n >= 1 && n<=x.length ){ index = n; };
```

```js
console.clear();
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#sidebar-btn').click(function() {
    $('#sidebar-nav').toggleClass('visible');
  });
});

var index = 0;

function plusIndex(n) {
  index = index + 1;
  showImage(index);
}

/* SLIDER */
showImage(1);

/* Slider function */
function showImage(n) {

  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slider-img");

  // for next slide - forward.
  if(n > x.length) { index = 1 };
  // for prev slide - backwards
  if(n < 1 ) { index = x.length /* last one */ };
  if(n >= 1 && n<=x.length ){ index = n; };         // ADD THIS CASE
  for(i=0; i<x.length; i++) 
  {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[index-1].style.display = "block";  
}
```

```css
.updates-box {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2rem;
}
.updates-item-headline {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.updates-item {
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 1rem auto;
}

.slider {
  position: relative;

}
.slider-img {
  position: absolute;

}
.slider .slider-btn {
  position: absolute; 
  color: black;
  width: 50px;
  border:none;
  border-radius: 25px;
  top: 190px; 
  font-size: 35px;
  margin:  1rem;
}
.slider #slide-btn2 {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}
.slider #slide-btn1:hover {
  box-shadow: 10px 0px 20px  0px black;
}
.slider #slide-btn2:hover {
  box-shadow: 10px 0px 20px  0px black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hero-box">
  <div id="slide-wrapper">
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="slide">
        <picture>
           <source media="(max-width: 620px)" srcset="img/hero-slider-mobile.jpg">
            <source media="(min-width: 621)" srcset="img/hero-slider-tablet.jpg">
           <img class="slider-img" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/cats" alt="Flowers">
        </picture>      
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <picture>
           <source media="(max-width: 620px)" srcset="img/slide-2-mobile.jpg">
            <source media="(min-width: 621)" srcset="img/slide-2-tablet.jpg">
           <img class="slider-img" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature" alt="Flowers">
        </picture>      
      </div>
      <button class="slider-btn" id="slide-btn1">&#10094;</button>
      <button class="slider-btn" id="slide-btn2">&#10095;</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="updates-box">
  <div class="updates-item-headline">
    <p> UPCOMING EVENT DATES</p>
  </div>
  <div class="updates-item">
    <img class="update-icon" src="img/dates-icon.png">
    <p><b>Thursday 3 August</b></p>
    <p> Open Seminar Enrollment</p>
  </div>
  <div class="updates-item">
    <img class="update-icon" src="img/dates-icon.png">
    <p><b>Thursday 3 August</b></p>
    <p> Open Seminar Enrollment</p>
  </div>
    <div class="updates-item-4">
    <img class="update-icon" src="img/dates-icon.png">
    <p><b>Thursday 3 August</b></p>
    <p> Open Seminar Enrollment</p>
  </div>  
</div>
```